# Mat-select is opening in full screen

Tags: angular, angular-material

We are working on an Angular 13 application and are currently implementing a material form.
From the examples are we implementing :-

```
<mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>State</mat-label>
        <mat-select>
            <mat-option>New York</mat-option>
            <mat-option>Washington</mat-option>
            <mat-option>Florida</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

[image]

which renders correctly

However,  on clicking the dropdown,  the options are stretching full screen, and is impossible to see the items.  We cant seen any custom CSS that would effect this, and now struggling to see what the issue could be..

[image]

Comment: This is happening to me too, you found something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit late but i solved it,
you have to set the themes of your application.
In my case i set a custom theme in `src/assets/styles/mytheme.scss`.

But you can use the default themes and it should work.